# WCF in Windows Mobile 6

Tags: wcf, windows-mobile

I have seen this issue on google, however, nobody seems to be able to solve it.  I am writing a Windows Mobile app that utilizes a WCF service that I created.  When I deploy this app to the device, it runs fine as do other non-mobile apps that consume this web service.  When I debug it (bluetooth or usb cradle connected), SOME of the web service calls will break causing a "The remote connection to the device has been lost..." error and instantly closes the app without any further debug information.  Others won't break it at all and allow me to continue debugging.  Also, about 5% of the time, the web service calls that do break it, allow me to debug it but most of the time, it gives me that error and crashes.

Any idea what is causing this?  I am at a loss.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is happening because it is a mobile device?

Sometimes, we get this while debuging a WCF client or service due to a timeout.

Is it always the same services that give you this error? Does it happen as soon as you enter the service?

If it is specific services, is there anything special about them?

Answer (score 0):

Update:  It was due to a third party SDK that was crashing my client that was consuming the web service.  All works well now.